# Can't Access Props in NativeScript Vue Modal

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm using a modal to show a listView and I want to pass the list into the modal as an array. I call the modal, like so:

```
this.$showModal(Picker, { props: { list: [

  { name: "Item 1" },
  { name: "Item 2" },
  { name: "Item 3" }

]}});
```

The modal loads fine, and I can see the props in the modal when I console.log

```
created: function(){
  console.log(this.list);
},
```

However, I can't access the props in the template or loop over them.

```
 <ListView for="item in listOfItems">
   <v-template>
     <Label :text="item.name" class="listItem" />
   </v-template>
 </ListView>
```

I have also tried:

```
<ListView :for="item in $props.list">
```

My full code for the modal component is below:

```
<template>
  <Page>

     <ListView for="item in listOfItems">
       <v-template>
        <Label :text="item.name" class="listItem" />
       </v-template>
     </ListView>

  </Page>
</template>

<script>

  export default {

    props: ["list"],

    created: function(){
      console.log(this.list);
    },

    data(){
      return {
        listOfItems: this.list
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Change `<ListView for="item in listOfItems">` to `<ListView for="item in list">`

Comment: Doesn't work :(

For some reason the props don't seem to be accessible from the template. I've also tried passing in a single value and add it to Label's text, but it just can't seem to access it.

Comment: Nope, it just loads a blank modal.

Comment: hm. Can you provide a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) like link (it would very helpful to debug)?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t know why, but when I changed the 
    data() return { 
so that the variable names are the same, 
    {animals: animals,
      vegetables: vegetables } 
it worked.

Didn’t have to do this for strings or integers, just objects.

Answer (score 0):

`<ListView for="item in $props.list">`

Remove colon?

I'm taking care of removing unnecessary `:` of head of `for` and refering to `$props` property when coding with NativeScript-Vue.